# Why is this SQL giving column cannot be resolved error?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I am trying to run a very simple `CASE...WHEN` statement:

```
SELECT userid, sum(end_time-start_time)/60 AS timespent_minutes, 
                    CASE WHEN webid = '324234' THEN 'CA'
                    ELSE 'Other' END AS storeloc
FROM time_spent_intervals
WHERE (ds = '2018-12-01')
GROUP BY userid, storeloc
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Error: SYNTAX_ERROR
>   line 6:38: Column 'storeloc' cannot be resolved

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL?

Comment: what's your table schema?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try repeating the expression in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT userid, sum(end_time-start_time)/60 AS timespent_minutes, 
       (CASE WHEN webid = '324234' THEN 'CA' ELSE 'Other' END) AS storeloc
FROM time_spent_intervals
WHERE ds = '2018-12-01'
GROUP BY userid, (CASE WHEN webid = '324234' THEN 'CA' ELSE 'Other' END) ;
```

Although MySQL allows column aliases for the `GROUP BY`, not all databases do.  I'm guessing that you are not really using MySQL.

Comment: Postgres (and Postgres derived databases), MySQL, BigQuery, PresoDB, and Hive all allow aliases in the `GROUP BY`.  Oracle, SQL Server, MS Access, Teradata, and DB2 do not.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Query always executes the query in the following order

```
FROM  
WHERE 
GROUP BY 
HAVING 
SELECT 
ORDER BY
```

You have referred the column alias defined in the SELECT class in GROUP BY. But GROUP BY will be executed before the SELECT statement. That is the reason for the error. Above suggested solution will suits your need.

Comment: This is absolutely NOT TRUE.  SQL Server -- as with all databases -- parses the query in the order you specify.  This explains the scoping rules for identifiers.  Basically all databases execute directed acyclic graphs, which are produced after complex optimization and have little relationship to the original query.